# Browser doesn't create cookie although set-cookie is exist in response header

Tags: spring-security, restful-authentication, setcookie

I'm creating the login function based on restful , spring security .

In client side when i use ajax to call login function in restful endpoint :

$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://192.168.0.2:8081/recruitment/api/login',
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("success");

```
            },
            data : {
                username : userName,
                password : password,
                redirect : 'home'

            },
            cache: false
        });
```

The response status is OK and i see the set-cookie option in response header :

Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=5CB1449126C9F5EFE365B0C43CAA0598; Path=/recruitment/; HttpOnly

But actually, no cookie created in client side . I don't know why ?

Could you please help me ?